# Is "that" necessary in the following case?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

> If there's wasn't a mess in the morning, it would *indeed* mean (that)
>   she'd been sleepwalking.

Do I need the *that* there? Why or why not?

Comment: Should "_If there's wasn't a mess_" be "_If there's a mess_" (as assumed in [Mark's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/408584/102510))? Or perhaps "_If there was a mess_".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Informally (and especially in speech) "that" is optional. Informality is suggested by your use of multiple contractions. For instance,

> "If there's a mess in the morning, it would indeed mean she'd been sleepwalking again."

Or

> "If there's a mess in the morning, it would indeed mean she's been sleepwalking again."